# Хорошо хоть – запятая

Tags: запятые

### "Хорошо, хоть он продолжает писать".

"Грамота.ру." предлагает ставить запятую после слова "хоть", но вот, допустим, если хочется сделать акцент на том, что он всё-таки продолжает писать, можно ли оставить пунктуацию такой же, как и в исходном предложении?

Comment: Ссылочку на Грамуту.ру дайте, пожалуйста. Это выглядит ошибочным советом, хотелось бы видеть подтверждение.

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=Хорошо+хоть .

Comment: @grizzly Я думаю, что имеется в виду вот эта дискуссия: "Хорошо хоть". Там и ссылочка есть, и примеры. http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6518

Comment: @grizzly, хочу ответить на Ваш комментарий, я просто ответила на поставленный вопрос, не трогая дискуссионный вопрос о возможности пунктуации без запятой. Частицы "хорошо", "благо" имеют тесные внешние и внутренние связи с другими классами слов: в них в разной степени присутствуют элементы значений наречий, пунктуация зависит от смысла, вкладываемого автором. Как в названной дискуссии: Хорошо хоть не арестовали.
Хорошо [и то], [что] хоть не арестовали.
Хорошо хоть [то], [что] не арестовали. Кстати, я бы написала без запятой, но школьникам понятнее с запятой.

Comment: Грамота.ру рекомендует ставить запятую после слова  "хоть", а не перед ним. Цитата: Правильно: Хорошо хоть, не арестовали. Запятая отделяет вводные слова.

Comment: Знаю, читала про мнение Грамоты, но знаю и мнения профессоров лингвистики.Кто как понимает. Более современный взгляд на слово хорошо=благо - это частица, т.е. без запятых, но если автор видит в нём вводное слово и хочет поставить запятую - его право. Вопрос лишь - где её ставить. Если акцент на том,что он всё-таки продолжает писать, то после "хоть". Вот об этом я и написала в ответе. А единого мнения нет.

Answer (score 2):

*Хорошо, хоть он продолжает писать*. При такой пунктуации усиливается слово ОН, частица является проклитиком и присоединяется к последующему слову, поэтому значение такое: хорошо, что хоть он пишет, а то никто не будет писать.

*Хорошо хоть, он продолжает писать*. При такой пунктуации частица хоть является энклитиком и относится к предыдущему слову хорошо.Значение: хорошо, что он продолжает писать, не остановился.

Comment: Хорошо, хоть он продолжает писать. Если запятая ставится перед словом "хоть", то это  союз с уступительным значением, а здесь уступительного значения нет, поэтому это неверная пунктуация. Смысл предложения может быть совершенно разным при разной постановке запятой. Сравните две ситуации (две точки зрения). (1) Хорошо хоть,  там не было женщин.  Или: Хорошо хоть там не было женщин. (2) Погуляли хорошо, хоть там и не было женщин.

Answer (score 1):

***Хорошо хоть, он продолжАет писать.***

Мне кажется, что в этом предложении запятая  нужна, но вообще в данной теме возможны варианты.

Сравним: (1) Хорошо хоть без последствий. (2) Хорошо хоть, что без последствий. В первом предложении пауза явно отсутствует.

Статус  ***хорошо хоть*** можно определить как **составную частицу с оценочным значением** (нет запятой) или как **вводное слово** (запятая ставится).

**Но это вопрос дискуссионный.** Например, на форуме Грамоты.ру он обсуждался, и там давалась оценка ответу с запятой, а также высказано мнение о составной частице.

http://gramota.ru/forum/spravka/14994

А пока определенности нет, в Нацкорпусе присутствуют **оба варианта.**

**Интересное решение у Пелевина:**

(1) ***Хорошо хоть глаза им завязали…*** (2) ***Хорошо хоть, не завтра и не послезавтра…***

В первом предложении у него, вероятно, частица, а во втором ― вводное слово. Тогда обособление зависит от структуры предложения.

В этом случае **варианты такие**:

Хорошо хоть (= к счастью), он продолжАет писать (вводное слово).

Хорошо хоть вообще пишет (частица).

Хорошо хоть, что он продолжает писать (СПП).

**Неверен вариант с запятой перед *хоть***: Хорошо, хоть он продолжает писать. Слово ***хоть*** занимает здесь позицию союза, но оно не является союзом со значением уступки.